# Servlets and session

Tags: java, servlets

Consider **servlet A** binds the user to a session like this:

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
```

and that same user soon after performs
a request on **servlet B** which belongs to the same application
of **servelt A**.

At this point When servlet B executes:

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
```

is session null?

Comment: Did you test it? What did you get? Just `sysout(session)` after that statment..

Comment: i get null...but i didn't expect that

Comment: If that really is happening than there must be something destroying the session in between those two calls. What is session expiration setting?

Answer (score 4):

Here are the possible reasons for this code to return null:

- the second call is sent after the session has timed out
- you restarted the server or redeployed the app between the two calls
- you restarted your browser between the two calls
- you used two different browsers or machines to perform the two calls
- the browser rejects cookies, and you didn't encode your URLs properly for url-rewriting session tracking to work
- another call between the two calls invalidated the session
- both servlets are in fact not in the same webapp

Answer (score 1):

[HttpServletRequest#getSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29)

`true` to create a new session for this request if necessary; `false` to return null **if there's no current session**

You need to check you receive session id in the request for Second servlet. You can do that using `getRequestedSessionId`

This can only happen if your session is got invalidated in between two calls or before browser gets `session id` you have made a call to `SeveletB`

Comment: But OP used `true` first to create new session, then used `false`. That should get him existing session.. But that's not happening. Its returning `null`.

Comment: Yes. This is only possible if `session id` is not with the browser while making second requests.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the order of servlets:

- if the servlet B will be invoked before A, the the session will not be created
- if the servlet A will be invoked before B, the session will be created and servlet B will have access to it.

In general, if you want to avoid automatical session creation - you must be sure that the code which uses the session is never executed BEFORE the code which creates the session.

So good practice is to redirect user from servlet B to servlet A if the session is null.

Comment: in my example servlet a is invoked first but does not create a session, then servlet b is invoked and creates a session and finally servlet a is invoked again to use that session created by servlet b.is that not legal ?

Comment: servlet A can not execute without creation the session. Something is wrong with your flow.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, `servletA` is called first and `servletB` next.

If nothing happens in addition as you have mentioned, you will receive the same session(**not null**) in `servletB` which used/created in `servletA`.

In servletA,

```
      getSession(true) in servletA means create and return the session if not 
      present otherwise return the existing session
```

In servletB,

```
      getSession(false) in servletB means return the existing session if present 
      otherwise return null.
```

Since you have already created a session in `servletA` for sure, you will receive **not null** session in `servletB` **provided nothing happens in between the two calls to wipe-out your session** e.g. session expires.